# Expressing a mild preference

Tags: phrase-requests, questions

I'm wondering how to express a very mild preference towards an option when being offered several choices in a conversation (e.g. when arranging a meeting time with a colleague).

I am familiar with the expressions .. ほうがいいです and .. がすきです, but both feel stronger than what I want to say.

Essentially I'm trying to complete this sentence with something natural-sounding:

「どちらでもいいですが、Xのほうが（・・・・・・）。」

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> a very mild preference

How about using どちらかと言えば、どちらかと言うと、[強]{し}いて言えば、強いて言うと etc. as in

> どちらでも大丈夫なんですが、どちらかと言うと、～～のほうがいいです。
>   どちらでも大丈夫なんですが、どちらかと言えば、～～のほうが[嬉]{うれ}しいです。/ありがたいです。
>   どちらでもいいんですが、[強]{し}いて言えば、～～のほうが・・・。

Comment: Apart from できれば，aren't these suggestions to some extent telling the OP how to express his preference more politely (or tentatively) rather then as a "mild preference", which I took  to mean as a weak preference (51% vs 90%). I think they  want to express this in more neutral or casual Japanese.

Comment: @Tim ああ、そうか～わかりました、直してみます。

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways but you want to be clear so perhaps the easiest is to use a different adjective to いい such as 便利. "Either is fine but X would be more convenient." If you can give the reason even better.